# How to catch global key (MediaPlayPause) when window is unfocused (like Youtube does it)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, keylistener

*Question:*
How to listen to MediaPlayPause keyboard event in unfocused tab.

*Background:*
I recently noticed that Youtube is able to Play/Pause the video when I press the Play/Pause Media button on the keyboard, *even when the browser tab/window is not in focus*.

This seems to only work in Chrome (I've tested in Chrome 74 on Windows 10), so there must be some Chrome-specific API method they're using to make it work, since keyboard events generally can't be accessed when the tab isn't in focus.

I'd like to achieve a similar functionality in a web-app, but can't figure out how. Therefore I ask of the greater collective if anyone knows how this is achieved?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Version 72. The media button doesn't do anything even if the tab is in focus and I've actually selected the video. So this is probably a newer feature.